# Applying a Custom Template for TextBox Header

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am developing a windows phone app and my requirements include to use a specific color theme and not use the default theme (Light/Dark/etc.) of the phone.

I'm stuck at formatting/templating the headers of textboxes. The following code in the app.xaml is not working:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Black"/>
</DataTemplate>

<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFBBB8B8"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"/>
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

Is there either a way just to configure the theme used or a way to implement the template for the headers?

Comment: Do you have a WP **Silverlight** or a WP 8.1 (and following) project? Only the latter one has a `Header` property. 
What does not work in your Code? I testet it and got no problems.
PS: App development has nothing to do with WPF.

Comment: @Koopakiller you're right code above does work so not sure the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to implement a Template on a `Page`

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Red" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox" Width="300" Height="80"
             Margin="20" Header="Headline"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox2" Width="300" Height="80"
             Margin="20" Header="Headline2"/>
</StackPanel>
```

or if you want the `Style` to apply to certain `TextBox` give it a Key

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="MyTextBoxStyle">
```

and apply to relevant `TextBox`

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox2" Width="300" Height="80"
         Margin="20" Header="Headline2" 
         Style="{StaticResource MyTextBoxStyle}"/>}"/>
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

It is really strange I tested the following:

```
  <Application.Resources>
        <Style  TargetType="TextBox" >
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFBBB8B8"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"/>
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="testing"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="DT1">
            <TextBlock Foreground="Green" Text="testing"/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style  TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="TextBoxStyle2">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFBBB8B8"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"/>
            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DT1}"/>
        </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

and in the mainpage

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox  Text="testing"/>
    <TextBox Margin="0,100,0,0" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle2}" Text="testing"/>
</Grid>
```

And it works, so I think the content from the binding is empty and appears not be working.